Practical Garuf?
I am writing an article about Garuf and Katum. According to Chazal, one can perform Garuf, which most Rishonim interpret as removing most of the coals from the fire before Shabbos. This practice was very practical when ovens were made of stone or earthenware, where even after removing the coals, the walls of the oven could remain hot for hours on end.
However, in modern times, with the widespread use of metal ovens that cool down relatively quickly once the heat source is removed/ turned off, is there any practical application of Garuf (not to be confused with Katum)?

A modern day oven can still stay hot for a few hours after it is turned off. You can turn it off just before candle lighting, and the food inside will be perfectly hot enough for your meal an hour or two later.

The oven itself keeps warm for maybe half an hour. The food, if covered, can keep its own heat for an extra 2 hours. Also, I don’t think an off-oven would be Garuf.  I would say once the oven is off, food would not be able to be cooked in it (besides Kali Habishul)
